# not able to access my local code to other machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, localhost

I need to test my site on IE.  I have Ubuntu installed.  My Rails app is running on `localhost:3000`.  Now, when I try to go to `myIP:3000`, I get the error:

> Site can't be reached.

I had previously used the same IP to access the server, and it worked. I am not sure why it no longer works.

Is there a way to fix this to make it work as I expect?  I don't want to push to Heroku every time I need to test on IE.

Comment: try using "http://myIp:3000" and make sure you have entered correct IP address and port number.

Comment: that's what I said in the question, I am trying the same..

Comment: I want you to add http:// at the begining

Comment: tried that as well, didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Method 1

> **Update:**
>
> No need to start with IP address. Thanks to [Thorin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1138557/thorin). Starting server with 0.0.0.0 will do the trick.
>
> ```
> rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
> ```

On a linux machine, type `ifconfig` and note down your local IP.

Run your server like this

`rails server -b 192.168.X.XXX -p 3000`

where you pass your local ip to `-b`

Now make sure both the machines are connected to your local Wi-Fi. On your windows machine navigate to `http://192.168.X.XX:3000`

#### Method 2

Install wine in your ubuntu machine and install IE preferable version. Will be easier to access everything from a single machine.

Comment: I checked my ip by clicking `show information`, and It showed `192.168.2.206` but with `ifconfig` It showed `127.0.0.1` and that worked

Comment: although the same IP, IE is not loading it.On chrome It did work

Comment: Are you connected over wifi or wire?

Comment: wired internet it is

Comment: when you type `ifconfig` usually you'll be shown eth0, lo & wlan0 by default unless you have done some modifications to your system. If you're connected over ethernet pick eth0 and if over wifi pick wlan0. You're looking for `inet addr:`. Take that ip address and start your rails server as mentioned in method 1. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: another issue with this method I am seeing is, `localhost:3000` doesn't work then

Comment: Of course that will not work. You have run it on a particular ip address. One solution is add this to your hosts file `192.168.X.XX localhost`, but that's really really **not recommended**. It will redirect eveything local to your server address now. So better install wine on your machine and install whatever window stuff you want. :)

Comment: Actually you do not need to start rails server with your IP address just run rails s -b 0.0.0.0

Comment: Thanks @thorin ,  I think  Suraj, that solves everything!